# ToroPHP5 .htaccess Cpanel error: No input file specified

Tags: php, .htaccess, input, url-rewriting, cpanel

htaccess and framework ToroPHP5

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is my php configuration:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2561075/info.pdf

When i try to access to some path:

http://domain.com/db

**Appear this error:**

```
No input file specified.
```